# Unity Ads: No cancel button in ads

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using unity ads package for my mobile game. Ads itself works fine, but cancel button is missing, and return button doesn't cancel the ad.
Here's the code i'm using to call ads:

```
public void ShowVideoForTry() {
    bool notMaxTries = GlobalManager.Instance.TriesManager.Tries < GlobalManager.Instance.TriesManager.MaxTries;
    if(!Advertisement.isInitialized) {
        Debug.LogWarning("Advertisement not initialized.");
    } else if(!Advertisement.IsReady()) {
        Debug.LogWarning("Advertisement not ready.");
    } else if(!notMaxTries) {
        Debug.LogWarning("Player has max tries already.");
    } else {
        Advertisement.Show(_config.rewardedAdsId);
    }
}
void IUnityAdsListener.OnUnityAdsDidError(string message) {
    Debug.LogError(message);
}
void IUnityAdsListener.OnUnityAdsDidFinish(string placementId, ShowResult showResult) {
    if (placementId == _config.rewardedAdsId) {
        if (showResult == ShowResult.Finished || showResult == ShowResult.Skipped) {
            GlobalManager.Instance.TriesManager.AddTry();
        }
    }        
}
void IUnityAdsListener.OnUnityAdsDidStart(string placementId) {
}
void IUnityAdsListener.OnUnityAdsReady(string placementId) {
}
```

Am I missing something? Is cancelling even supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you showing a rewarded video ads? Unity's reward video doesn't allow cancelling.

If you are showing a non-rewarded video ads, you can toggle allowing skipping in Unity's Dashboard. More info on that here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ads@3.4/manual/MonetizationPlacements.html

Comment: I'm showing a rewarded video ads. Is there no way to show a warning like "you won't get any rewards, if you close the video" using Unity Ads?

Comment: No, there is no way as of right now. You can try contacting Unity Ads Support if you want to ask about that feature https://unityads.unity3d.com/help/help/contact